# H1 Bottom Border Underline

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where I am trying to underline my h1 with a border-bottom, but it extends behind my picture (to the left). I would like the underline to extend to the very end of the page. Here is my code:

```
HTML:
<div id="content">
<img src="http://imageshack.us..."/>
    <h1>About me</h1
        <p>Info about me....</p>
    <h2>Contact info</h2>
        <p>Phone:my number</p>
        <p>Email: my email</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content  {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#content img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#content h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 15px 0px 5px 0px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

**Note:** I am a novice coder - so if this is not possible or there are any other ways to do this let me know!

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```css
#content h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 15px 0px 5px 0px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will only underline the contents. Not the whole line.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this is happening is because you haven't set a width on the `h1`. So it is naturally going to extend the entire page width. To solve this, add a `width` property, and you should be good to go. This is what the code looks like now

```
#content h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 15px 0px 5px 0px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  width:200px; /*Change this to whatever value that you want*/
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BpS2/)

As others have stated, you can also use `inline-block` on the `h1`. This would normally put everything on the same line as the `h1`, but since it is a `p` below it, this is not the case, because `p` elements natrually have a CSS of `display:block;`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BpS2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 display: inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrfB7/1/